# Google Apps ScriptのWebアプリが3-4日後に403エラーを返す

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Scriptで作成したWebアプリをデプロイしたところ、3-4日後に403エラーが返るようになりました。

このスクリプトはGoogleスプレッドシートの内容を返すもので、特定のサイトから6時間おきにデータを取得するために使用しています。デプロイ後、最初の数日間は問題なく機能していましたが、3-4日が経過すると403エラーが発生し始めました。デプロイし直すと問題なく動作するのですが、この状況が繰り返されます。

デプロイの設定は以下の通りです：

- Execute as: Me
- Who has access: Anyone

appscript.jsonの内容は以下の通りです。

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

doGet()の内容は以下の通りです。

```
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const result = {
    KEY: foobar(ss) // データ取得のための様々な処理...
    ...
  };
  const resultJson = JSON.stringify(result);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(resultJson)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Google Cloud Communityの[この投稿](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Workspace-Q-A/AppsScript-Web-Deployment-always-stops-working-after-3-4-days/m-p/515492#M9721)はとてもこの状況に似ているように思えますがこの質問では明確な回答が得られていないようです。

[このerror messageの箇所](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script?tab=readme-ov-file#error-messages)の上から５つ目の「Google Drive - Access Denied」がまさに同じエラーです。

どなたかこの403エラーの原因や解決策についての洞察をお持ちではないでしょうか？
不足している情報があれば、教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。